# Call JS function in Wordpress, noob question?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have simple JavaScript function

```
function hide()
{
    document.getElementById('div_sc_1').style.display = "none";
}
```

in my themefolder/js file I put

```
function add_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'quest', 
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/quest.js', 
        array('jquery'), 
        '1.0.0', 
        false
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_scripts' );
```

in my function.php.

I can call my function from an `<input type="submit" onClick="hide();">`

BUT I want make something like that in my function.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET[xxx]))
{
<script>
hide()
</script>
}
?>
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe try this `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { hide(); });`

Comment: Thank You for quick answer it works very well !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are adding it directly in the dom, so It may run before the target element even exists, Javascript requires an element to available first in order to do its job.

You have to add it once the document is fully loaded so that it can work.
Maybe try this `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { hide(); });`

If you add it after the document is ready then Javascript will be able to find your element and execute related functions.

Comment: This may work, but you should explain **why** it works.

Comment: @IsaacVidrine I was eventually doing that, before that your negative mark appeared, explained please remove the negative

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. I have understand why it doesn't work, all about timing of loading. Now, the div hides just after it appears. Can I hook this action a lttle before for not even having the initial display div ?

Comment: maybe then just use CSS in a header file, if don't want this div at all. and when you again want to have this div letter sometime you can change CSS property with javascript

Comment: @WasimSayyed since you've updated your answer, I'll do the right thing and remove my downvote. However, trolling isn't a place for SO. It wasn't a negative comment, it was stating facts. You can't get mad at people for pointing them out. If you can't handle that, you don't belong in the SO community.

Comment: @Wasim Sayyed You're right, i was taking the problem in the wrong way, better for me to hide everything with css and show() with jquery. thanks for help !!

Comment: @Isaac Vidrine thanks for trying to keep SO community S+ tier !